# How can I calculate the longitude/latitude span of a Google Map for iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, google-maps

The only potential candidate for what I'm trying to achieve is the GMSCamera object. It has target which is the lat/lng center of the map and a zoom property. How can I use these together to figure out the span of map in latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I needed to use the projection property of GMSMapView and from there get the visibleRegion. This contained the information I needed.